# How do I customize the color of HTML attributes in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, textmate

How do I customize the color of HTML attributes like class="", href="", src="", style="" etc. in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=altrue.CustomColoring or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-highlight

Answer (score 9):

Open the `settings.json` file and add this:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope":"entity.other.attribute-name",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#ca9829",
                "fontStyle": "italic"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

You can set the theme too to only apply with that one, not globally. [Here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme) is a know-how for all this.

Comment: Is there a way to target only a specific attribute like `class`?

Comment: If someone wants to limit this effect to a concrete theme, just put the `textMateRules ` inside a field with the name of the theme you want to customize,  like : `"[Default Light+]": { "textMateRules": [{.....}]}`